# Phrasal verb: 'to read for'

Tags: grammar

Does the following sentence sound right?

> Read the operating instructions for directions on replacing the housing.

Comment: `read for` is no phrasal verb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Consult](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/consult)*** or ***[refer to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/refer+to)*** may be more specific for your needs.

Example:
For instructions on how to ... please refer to the manual.

Answer (score 2):

This is definition #5 of *for* in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for)

> Having (the thing mentioned) as a reason or cause: *Aileen is proud of her family for their support*

Getting directions is the reason to read the instructions.